# Singing in TelegramClient telethon

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

After running the code, I try to enter a password (but I don’t have it) and can’t enter anything. I use VS Code

- Please enter your phone (or bot token): `79622222693`
- Please enter the code you received: `40589`
- Please enter your password: `(CANT ENTER ANYTHING, AND I DON'T HAVE ANY PASS ON MY ACCOUNT)`

Tried different accounts.

```
    from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
    api_id = 973111111111145
    api_hash = '05c6f86e67922222222222225ad7615a8'

    client = TelegramClient('sessi1onname', api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
```

Comment: did you enabled the Two-Step Verification for this telegram account ??

Comment: No. Two-Step Verification is disabled

Comment: did you try another IDE or are you sure about the enter in a right field ?? .. do you need to share my code with you??

Answer (score 0):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 0
api_hash = ''

with TelegramClient('sessi1onname', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.get_messages('me', "telethon sign in success")
```

use this code and then check your Saved Messages in telegram. will work for you. way you are trying is not sync!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this code does't work too. Because i can't enter password. The problem not in the code, but probably in environment. And also I want to add that problem reproduced  in *.py file too, if I started it directly

Answer (score 0):

With enabled 2-step verification to fix I've done:

In file: telethon\client\auth.py I changed in line 22:

```
lambda: getpass.getpass('Please enter your password: ')
```

to my actual password.