# How to connect to Telegram using Telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

maybe this is a recurrent topic however I looked before and found the list below that did not solved my problem:

- [Singing in TelegramClient telethon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590974/singing-in-telegramclient-telethon)
- [When starting client the code is asking for phone/bot token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790772/when-starting-client-the-code-is-asking-for-phone-bot-token)
- [Hosting a Telethon User BOT on google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884537/hosting-a-telethon-user-bot-on-google-app-engine)
- [How to search for groups and channel in telegram using telethon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016386/how-to-search-for-groups-and-channel-in-telegram-using-telethon)

So far none of those solutions helped me.

- I am not using 2FA on Telegram

My code is like below

```
import configparser
import json
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
from datetime import date, datetime

from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, functions
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import (PeerChannel)
nest_asyncio.apply()

# some functions to parse json date
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return list(o)

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    
class MyBot:
    api_id = None
    api_hash = None
    phone = None
    username = None
    channel = None
    debug = "False"
    client = None
    loaded = "False"
      
    def readConfig (self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("config.ini")
        
        # Setting configuration values
        self.api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
        self.api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
        
        self.api_hash = str(self.api_hash)
        
        self.phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
        self.username = config['Telegram']['username']
        
        self.channel = config['Telegram']['channel']
        self.debug = config['Telegram']['debug']
        if self.api_id != None:
            if self.api_hash != None:
                if self.phone != None:
                    if self.username != None:
                        if self.channel != None:
                            self.loaded = "True"
    
    def printConfig (self):
        if self.debug == "True":
            print("api_id: "+self.api_id)
            print("api_hash: "+self.api_hash)
            print("phone: "+self.phone)
            print("username: "+self.username)
        else: print("Debug if False")
    
    async def createClient(self):
        if self.loaded == "True":
            print("Creating Client")
            client = TelegramClient(session="session", api_id =self.api_id, api_hash =self.api_hash)
            await client.start()
            # Ensure you're authorized
            if not await client.is_user_authorized():
                await client.send_code_request(self.phone)
                try:
                    await client.sign_in(self.phone, input('Enter the code: '))
                except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                    await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))
        
            search = 'linux'
            result = await client(functions.contacts.SearchRequest(
                q=search,
                limit=100
            ))
            print(result.stringify())            

myBot = MyBot()
myBot .readConfig()
myBot .printConfig()
#myBot .createClient()
asyncio.ensure_future(myBot .createClient())
```

I also have a config.ini file on the same folder as this code with the alraedy setup for my credentials to use the Telegram API.

When I run this code it returns

- api_id: 1234567 (fake value here)
- api_hash: xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy
- phone: +
- username: @myIdonTelegram
- Creating Client
- Please enter your phone (or bot token):

I can't escape this prompt asking me my phone and even if i type it nothing happens
What am I missing? Why it keeps me asking my phone and how to by pass it?

Comment: The code you are following is kinda using an old version of telethon. Currently you only need an instance of TelegramClient then you should use client.start() that's all.
Check https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html#quick-start for more

Comment: Not working either.  If I replace my old createClient method by             client = TelegramClient(session="session", api_id =self.api_id, api_hash =self.api_hash)
            me = await client.get_me()
            print(me.stringify())            
            async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
                print(dialog.name, 'has ID', dialog.id)    nothing prints after Creating Client